# It seems that font spacing was changed. Why it could happen?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have a strange behavior of Winform application that I develop. The font spacing just became bigger so it affects the buttons look & feel and the whole form: some of the text are cut off, while some other text are missing due to this extra spacing.
Please see a screenshot (I just highlighted errors with two arrows, but you can see that it happens in all fonts of textboxes, labels etc.)

I must say I didn't change anything on application nor this host (Windows 7) settings.
The same application works well on another Windows 7 hosts.

The screenshot with red arrows demonstrates how it looks with the extra spacing.
The screenshot with green arrows shows how it looks on another host (as expected).

Do you know why it happened and how to rollback to previous font spacing?
Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `Control Panel --> Appearance and Personalization --> Display` To see what the Fonts Text Size is set for. A lot of newer PC's and Laptops with higher resolution Displays are being shipped set for Medium(125%).

---

Edit.

From the comments it appears that using the procedure documented in this [Microsoft Article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26) on how to reset the default font settings worked.

From Link:

1. Open Fonts by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel,
   clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Fonts.
2. In the left pane, click Font settings.
3. Click Restore default font settings.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the issue. I checked that before I post this questions. It's configured as "Smaller  - 100%"

Comment: @user986086 Are you using the Default System Font? On my system it is Segoe UI 11

Comment: Mark, where do I check it?  Thx

Comment: @user986086 Right Click on Desktop select Personalize go to the bottom and click on the `Window Color` Link, scroll to the bottom and select advanced appearance settings. That will bring up the `Window Color and appearance` dialog you can check your fonts there.

Comment: @user986086 You also can take a look at this [article](http://windows7themes.net/how-to-change-windows-7-default-font.html) It appears the previous message was relating to System Fonts. If this is a clean system the only thing I can suggest is to compare the two for any differences, but I am sure that you are doing that already. You also might want to look at this [MIcrosoft article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26) on how to reset the Font Settings.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I read Microsoft's article and restored the font settings. That's working!